# Mysql getting the lapse dates which type is varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am trying to get the dates which is less than today or due dates on mysql database, the problem is the date field type is varchar, my code is below i able to get less than dates but its not including the year, i need the month/day/year as a output, i do not own the database i just have a read only connection and can only make this type of queries, i am using PHP.

```
//i did now include the whole query code below is my query string.

$now = date('m/d/Y');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM todos WHERE DATE(due_date) < '$now'";

//other query here.
```

My output is below the date today is 07/03/2017

```
06/02/2018
05/13/2016
05/23/2017
04/15/2015
04/24/2019
```

Looking at my output it manage to get the due dates but only by month, some dates are still valid or the due is next year,any advice would be great! thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not a problem. Just change the data type of the dates column

Comment: One of my problem is i cannot change the data type of the database i was  only given a read only access, the main developer is also not open for change its sad actually.

Comment: Extricate yourself from this situation as quickly as you can

Comment: Thanks for the response and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a regular date and just use the database for the comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM todos 
WHERE str_to_date(due_date, '%m/%d/%Y') < curdate();
```

There is no need to pass in the current date from the application -- unless you specifically are aware of issues with time zones.

Never compare dates as strings.  Well, if you have to, be sure you are using the ISO format YYYY-MM-DD (with or without hyphens).

Comment: Note that this query cannot use an index, so it's pretty horrendous

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Feel free to answer with a query than *can* use an index in this case.

Comment: Hence my comment above

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I take the comment personally.  The issue is the data structure the OP has chosen, storing a date in a bad format.  There really isn't a reasonable query that could use an index, so this query is fine.

Comment: Agreed, the issue *is* the bad data structure.